# AS3 Loader hangs / doesn't fire COMPLETE

Tags: actionscript-3, loader

I have a font class which loads a png file and an xml file which specifies where the glyphs are placed on the bitmap. The font load function kicks off 2 loaders, one for the png and one for the xml. When they're both complete, an initialization function runs. Strangely, everything works fine when I run the app from Flash Builder and it works fine in IE, but when I use chrome, and am not running through Flash Builder, AND the content has been loaded once before (clearing browser cache fixes the issue) then the following line hangs:

```
public function bitmapLoadComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    mObject = LoaderInfo(evt.target).content;  // <--- hangs here
    itemLoaded();
}
```

mObject is declared as follows:

```
public var mObject:*;
```

itemLoaded decrements a counter (which is initialized to 2) and if it's zero, then it figures both assets have loaded and runs the init function.

Any ideas?

The assets are located here:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/IceCreamSoftware/letters0.png
https://s3.amazonaws.com/IceCreamSoftware/letters.bitmapfont

Comment: A Loader can also fire an `IO_Error` event, make sure it does not get fired. Listen to it, and in case this went wrong, either restart, parse and display, or replace assets with something else.

Comment: Ugh, my bad, looks like I forgot to pass in a LoaderContext(true) which seems to be triggering a security sandbox violation. Disabling the Chrome built-in flash player made a nice dialog pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to pass a LoaderContext with checkPolicyFile set to true to the load() method of the Loader object. This was causing a security sandbox violation which the Chrome embedded Flash player wasn't notifying me about. Disabling the built in player and using the debug plugin caused a dialog to pop which showed me what was going on. All good lessons learnt. What is strange is that:

```
1) Clearing the browser cache allowed the content to be loaded one time in Chrome
2) It always worked in IE
```